# How to get updates for Mathematica V10

Tags: version-10

As you know, *Mathematica* V10 has just been released and I think a lot of updates will be released. However, I don't see any command in the help menu to update (which is present in most other software).

How would we know if an update is available or not?

I am using trial version of V10.

[image]

Comment: Does this also affect the student version? The link told me what was in the update, but it doesn't tell me *how* to get it. The bugs are *KILLING* me in physics.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We can push paclet updates out directly, I think PacletManager guarantees that you'll have them within a week (as long as you have an internet connection).

This only works for certain functionality that has been written in the paclet form (e.g. Machine Learning, Dataset, SemanticImport). I'm really excited about that, because we can respond quickly to what our customers need, and if they find bugs we can potentially address them very fast.

The kernel can't be upgraded this way, however. And of course a lot of functionality lives directly in the kernel. Point releases are how the kernel gets updated.

Point releases, of which the next is of course 10.0.1 and is supposed to happen in the next few weeks (not an official promise), will require manual download. I imagine we'll send an email when that happens.

Comment: Does this mean that Machine Learning & Dataset may get updated in the background without my knowledge?  Does it mean that two installations of M 10.0.0 may have different versions of Dataset?  If so, how can I find out which version of Dataset (or Machine Learning or SemanticImport) I am running at the moment?

Comment: @Szabolcs you can write PacletInformation["Dataset"] (or "MachineLearning") to see what version you currently have. And you can turn auto-updates off by putting $AllowDataUpdates = False in your init.m.

Answer (score 10):

I know link-only answers are discouraged, but in this case I think it is the best answer available:

- http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html

Comment: Thanks a lot.I want also to congratulate you for getting 99k reputation and soon you will start your 100k+ reputation. Millions congratulations :)

Answer (score 3):

Update: The point releases are *supposed* to be automatically available through your Wolfram User Portal under My Products and Services. In my case, it hadn't been updated. I contacted support via their chat, and they changed the link for me manually. If you haven't gotten the email yet, you might want to pursue this route. Hope that helps.