# Paclets updating awareness and tracking

Tags: system, paclets

**Edit From the author of this question**

**This question is obsolete**
Since 2016 there is a lot of new stuff concerning Paclets.
They are now documented.
**End of the Edit**

It turns out that some silent updating may be done in our computers with paclets. See for example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124703/5467). How are we aware that something has been changed ? Can we track updating/versions of paclets ?

One can inspect the dates of the files in the Paclets directory, but in the case of the example above, the date of the file was anterior to the release of the paclet (a few days). I couldn't say if something new had been downloaded, but in fact it was the case because the mentioned bug had disappeared.

Also, do paclets [from non-official paclet sites](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132649/12) also auto-update?  Is it possible to adjust the updating frequency, or disable updating?  Is it possible to do it separately for each site?

Comment: Personally I am very interested in being alerted about any silent updates that may change functionality (e.g. fix bugs).  I am less interested in data paclets and even less interested in documentation changes.

Comment: I find that the frontier between "functionality changes" and "new paclets" is not so clear. Maybe new "functionalities" can only be introduced with paclets when things are experimental (but not otherwise). Of course this mainly concern the problem bug fix/new bug.

Comment: This "feature" is potentially disastrous for any kind of serious scientific research, as it can render reproducibility impossible.

Comment: @Karsten 7.  Idem for industry, don't forget it ! , though, personally, I'm a hobbyist.

Comment: FWIW, there's ``PacletManager`Package`$managerData``, e.g., ``"LastWolframAutoUpdate" /. PacletManager`Package`$managerData``, ``"LastUpdatedSiteDate" /. PacletManager`Package`$managerData``.  I thought I got this and other info from this site, but I can't find it.  Maybe it was on Community. Or in Chat. One could use it to poll the paclet manager, I suppose, but there doesn't seem to be much info about what's in the updates.

Comment: I'm just discovering this [strongly related answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54640/5467). See also the comments ( `PacletInformation["Dataset"]` )

Comment: Related: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/974137

Comment: Another example of a bug fixed by paclet update can be found in [(88537)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88537/142).

Comment: [related](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34946715#34946715)

Comment: [related (existence of `PacletFind[]`)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153761/5467)

Comment: [related (2 kind of Paclets)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78972/5467)

Answer (score 20):

This posting is not a complete answer.  Rather, it is a spelunking report concerning the kernel initialization sequence in version 11.0.1 as it relates to automatic paclet updating.

In summary, every three days the system initialization sequence will automatically update paclets that are loaded from `$PacletSite`.  `$PacletSite` is normally *http://pacletserver.wolfram.com*, although malicious software could change that.

The automatic updating will not occur if the kernel is started with either the *-nopaclet* or *-layoutpaclets* command line arguments, but these arguments have other consequences as well.  We can also `$AllowInternet = False`, but this has wider consequences too.

Other paclet sites are not updated by this mechanism.  However, there is nothing stopping a loaded paclet from installing its own mechanism.  Furthermore, the system sometimes updates other paclets on-demand during normal operation -- usually, but not always, data paclets.  This latter behaviour will need to be the subject of a future spelunking report.

**System Initialization Details**

For those who wish to follow along, define the following function:

```
opensys[args__] :=
  {$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", args} // FileNameJoin // NotebookOpen
```

System initialization begins in the file:

```
opensys["Kernel", "SystemResources", $SystemID, "sysinit.m"];
```

As part of the start-up, `` PacletManager`Package`preparePacletManager[] `` is invoked.  The definition for this function is in:

```
opensys["Autoload", "PacletManager", "Kernel", "Manager.m"];
```

It calls `` PacletManager`Package`initializePacletManager `` from the same file.  If the kernel is started up with an option *-nopaclet* or *-layoutpaclets* on the command line, then it sets the variable `` PacletManager`Package`$pmMode `` to be `"ReadOnly"`, or `"Normal"` otherwise.  Later, it calls `` PacletManager`Package`initializeSites `` which can be found in this file:

```
opensys["Autoload", "PacletManager", "Kernel", "Services.m"];
```

If the mode is not *read-only*, then it calls `` PacletManager`Services`Private`doWeeklyUpdate `` from the same file.  This will check the paclet information accessible from `` PacletManager`Services`Private`getPacletSiteData[] ``.  It extracts the paclet information for the site contained in `$PacletSite`, whose value is normally:

```
$PacletSite
(* "http://pacletserver.wolfram.com" *)
```

If the last successful update of that site is older than three days, then `PacletSiteUpdate` is called upon that site.

Nowhere along this tour do we find evidence of any fine-grained control mechanisms for this update activity.  We can use of aforementioned command line arguments, or set `$AllowInternet` to be `False`, but these have wider consequences.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the bounty despite my response being skeletal (apologies).  Such are the perils of acclamation...   :)