# How to remove a paclet downloaded from Wolfram Research Server?

Tags: packages, installation, paclets

How can I remove a paclet that was automatically downloaded when I used a function for the first time (i.e. `NetChain`)?

I believe the download was faulty, preventing me from using any of the functions from that paclet (e.g. ElementwiseLayer, etc.). That's why I want to redownload it. If I understand correctly, paclets are downloaded from the Wolfram Research Server when an uncommon function such as `NetChain` or `Sound` are used for the first time (indicated by a blue progress bar under the cell).

Comment: It is normally considered safe to delete the entire Paclets folder in AppData\Roaming (if on windows). The missing data will be redownloaded next time you need it. See also [Mathematica 10.0.x freezes in Initializing kernels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92931/27951) and answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `PacletFind` to find the installed versions, of the paclet, for exmaple:

```
paclets = PacletFind["*MX*"]
(*{Paclet[MXNetLink,11.1.0,<>]}*)
```

Then evaluated `PacletUninstall` to remove said paclet.  For example

```
PacletUninstall[ paclets[[1]] ]
```

I recommend using `Part` to select the paclet.  If you copy/paste, you'll need to be careful to select the visible expression along with its interpretation.  It's a little to easy to select just the displayed `Paclet["foo",<>]` without the interpretation.

If you like to see where the paclets are installed, use the following and again, be careful about directly copying the outputs:

```
Table[{paclet, "Location" /. PacletInformation[paclet]}, {paclet, 
   paclets}] // TableForm
```

Comment: Do you know how I can look for the directory of paclet listed by `PacletFind`?

Comment: `"Location" /. PacletInformation[paclet]`

Comment: Or `paclet["Location"]`