# Removing ResourceObject and other resources downloaded from Wolfram servers/

Tags: neural-networks, resource-management

What happens with recourses downloaded from Wolfram Servers? I have recently been playing with their [neural net library](http://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository), until I noticed that each model is takes up a lot of space.

How do delete these files and where are they stored?

Comment: You could try the method [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153752) to look for the paclet corresponding to the neural net you want to remove.