# Remove or Uninstall a package

Tags: packages, installation

strangely enough, I cannot find on the internet (nor the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=remove%20package) of Mathematica) the proper information on how to remove an installed package.

I installed GTPack, an amazing tool for doing group theory, but I want to remove it and install it again. I can find the package in `~/.Mathematica/Applications`, but I don't know if it's sufficient to remove the folder to uninstall it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this helpful?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153761/4999

Comment: `GTPack` is installed as an Application. The location depends on platform and whether it was installed for the current user or all users. `FileNames["*", FileNameJoin@{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]` or `FileNames["*", FileNameJoin@{$BaseDirectory, "Applications"}]`. Deleting the directory should be sufficient.

Comment: There is no universal method to install and uninstall packages. How did you install GTPack? If you copied it to that location then yes, you can just delete it from there. If it came with its own installer, then I suggest you contact its authors and ask them about uninstalling. You can also ask them not to try to write their own installer. Suggest to them to use paclets instead. The installation and uninstallation would be a simple PacletInstall/PacletUninstall.

Comment: Unfortunately, many package authors try to create their own installers, which are are often far from perfect, do not work in all situations, or do dubious things. I do not know if this is the case for GTPack because it cannot be downloaded with registration. However, I can say that at this point I am very distrustful of any Mathematica package that has its own installer instead of using standard mechanisms: ideally, they should use paclets. Otherwise, they should ask the user to copy the package to $UserBaseDirectory/Applications manually (in which case they'll know how to uninstall).